# How to make different size image and store them in django?

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I am new to Django and I searched but couldn't really find what I want. My problem is:

There is a form where a user can upload the image. What I want is, I want to create different size of that image and store it in a database. I used `sorl-thumbnail` and created the different sizes images to display in the template but I couldn't find the way to store them?

```
{%for hotel in hotel_images %} 

       <div class="container">
         <h2>Card Image</h2>

              <div class="card" style="width:400px">

                 {% thumbnail hotel.hotel_Main_Img "100x100" crop="center" as im %}
                        <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
                  {% endthumbnail %}
                     <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">{{hotel.name}}</h4>

                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">See Profile</a>
                       </div>

              </div>
        </div>


{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [ImageKit](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)